# Probability of satisfying the congruent mod equation

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, st.statistics, congruences

I'm wondering about the probability of picking three different numbers $x,y,z$ out of the set $[50]=\left\{ 1,2,3,...,50\right\}$ satisfying the equation: $$xyz\equiv \gcd(x,y,z)\mod 7$$ I started out by identifying a set of possible events $\Omega$ that is, the set of all three-element subsets. Cardinality $|\Omega|={50 \choose 3}$. But I have trouble determining the cardinality of the set of favorable events: $$\mathcal{M}=\left\{ \left\{ x,y,z\right\}\in\Omega: xyz\equiv \gcd(x,y,z)\mod 7 \right\} $$
My efforts and observations:

1. **Some simplification of congruent mod equation.**

Because $\gcd(x,y,z)|x \ \& \gcd(x,y,z)|y \ \& \gcd(x,y,z)|z$, it will take place: $$\text{gcd}^3(x,y,z)|xyz$$
So there is $x',y',z'$ such that $xyz=\text{gcd}^3(x,y,z)x'y'z'$ so the equation can be written: $$xyz\equiv \gcd(x,y,z)\mod 7$$ $$\text{gcd}^3(x,y,z)x'y'z'\equiv \gcd(x,y,z)\mod 7$$ $$\gcd(x,y,z)\left( \text{gcd}^2(x,y,z)x'y'z'-1\right)\equiv 0\mod 7$$ $7$ as it is prime, this should be equivalent:
$$\gcd(x,y,z)\equiv 0\mod 7 \ \ \text{OR} \ \  \text{gcd}^2(x,y,z)x'y'z'\equiv 1\mod 7$$ The first congruence is satisfied when $x,y,z$ are multiples of $7$. In the set $[50]$ is $\left\lfloor \frac{50}{7} \right\rfloor=7$ multiples of $7$. So the first congruence is satisfied for ${7 \choose 3}=35$ such threes $x,y,z$. How to calculate how many numbers satisfy the second congruence is more problematic for me.

2. **Numerical calculations**

I wrote a program that counts these triples that satisfy the congruence. The program counted: $$|\mathcal{M}|=2079$$ I have tried to notice a pattern in the solutions. For example, I researched what $\gcd$ are possible for threes that belong to $\mathcal{M}$:

[image]
3. **Generalization of the problem**

I was thinking about making a generalization to any set $[n]$. Then let $|\Omega_n|={n \choose 3}$ and: $$\mathcal{M}_n=\left\{ \left\{ x,y,z\right\}\in\Omega_n: xyz\equiv \gcd(x,y,z)\mod 7 \right\} $$ And we are looking for: $$\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{M}_n)= \frac{\left| \mathcal{M}_n\right| }{\left| \Omega\right| } = \frac{\left| \mathcal{M}_n\right| }{ {n \choose 3}  } $$ Using the earlier program, I drew the distribution $\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{M}_n)$ vs $n$:
[image]
It turns out that local minima occur in arithmetic intervals and occur for $n=5,12,19,26,33,40,47,...$ rather, it is not a coincidence that this sequence differs $7$. In contrast, local maxima occur for $n=4,11,18,25,32,39,46,...$ the question of the limit of the sequence $\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{M}_n)$ also seems interesting: $$ \lim_{n \to  \infty } \mathscr{P}(\mathcal{M}_n)\approx\frac{539}{5000}$$ although I'm more interested in how to solve this problem analytically.

Best regards MK

Comment: Clearly if one of $x,y,z$ is divisible by 7 then they all must be, so we can reduce to the case where all of them are coprime to 7. Denoting $k = gcd(x,y,z)$ we can write $x = a \cdot k, y = b \cdot k, z = c \cdot k$, and it is enough to solve the equation $abc = \frac{1}{k^2}$ where $gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

Comment: Yes, but that's an equation: $$abc = \frac{1}{k^2}$$ is $\mod 7$? What should I substitute for $a,b,c$?

Comment: Can anyone help please? I have no other ideas for counting the solutions.
 

PS This is not my homework, I ask out of curiosity :)

Comment: The way I would think about it is to condition on gcd(x, y, z) = const and then count how many solutions are possible. Under this condition, a could be in the range 50/k, b in the same range and then to count c you might need to condition on gcd(a,b) being something again. (x =ak, y = bk, z = ck).